# Integration with Encompass - Method not found error

Tags: .net

I am facing issue when trying to push data to Encompass from sales force. There was a Encompass SDK update to 17.4 and we tried to add the latest dll to application. Now facing an error when we initiate a session with Encompass(Session is a part of EllieMae.Encompass.Client library).

Code:

```
Session session = new Session(); // This is where the error is occurring
session.Start(EncompassConnetURl, username, password);
```

> Error:
>   ===Error Message Start===
>
> Method not found:
>       'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
>
> EllieMae.EMLite.Common.EnGlobalSettings.get_HttpClientCustomHeaders()'.

Comment: I'm interested in talking to people with EllieMae experience, if you wouldn't mind having a conversation with me reach out to me at mark.squires@ramp51.com

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error recently. to fix I had to change the properties of the "Encompass Objects" reference and change the "copy local" property to false. this seemed to work for me. I think the error was caused by a recent version update as this was working before.

Comment: Duan Walker I'm interested in talking to people with EllieMae experience, if you wouldn't mind having a conversation with me reach out to me at mark.squires@ramp51.com